# How to add a `billing_project` to a group in GCP Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

I am unable to make user groups in GCP using terraform: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_identity_group

There is a warning about using the application default credentials:

> If you are using User ADCs (Application Default Credentials) with this resource, you must specify a billing_project and set user_project_override to true in the provider configuration. Otherwise the Cloud Identity API will return a 403 error. Your account must have the serviceusage.services.use permission on the billing_project you defined.

I am using the Application Default Credentials.

Here is the error I get when I try to terraform apply my code:

```
Error: Error creating Group: googleapi: Error 403: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the cloudidentity.googleapis.com. We recommend configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/. If you are getting this error with curl or similar tools, you may need to specify 'X-Goog-User-Project' HTTP header for quota and billing purposes. For more information regarding 'X-Goog-User-Project' header, please check 
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "consumer": "projects/764086051850",
│       "service": "cloudidentity.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "SERVICE_DISABLED"
│   }
│ ]
│
│   with google_cloud_identity_group.group,
│   on groups.tf line 10, in resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "group":
│   10: resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "group" {
│
```

As you can see, it is a 403 error, just like in the warning. I had also already tried enabling the api by following these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/setup
So I'm fairly certain the enabling of the API is not the actual issue, I believe the issue is what the terraform documentation warned about.

The warning says to specify `billing_project` and set `user_project_override` to true, but I don't know where to do that. As a guess I tried putting them as arguments to my terraform script but it didn't work (kind of expected because they weren't listed as arguments in the terraform documentation)

```
$ terraform apply
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on groups.tf line 14, in resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "group":
│   14:   billing_project = var.project_id
│ 
│ An argument named "billing_project" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on groups.tf line 15, in resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "group":
│   15:   user_project_override = true
│ 
│ An argument named "user_project_override" is not expected here.
```

My code:

```
variable "domain_name"{
    type = string
    default = "martiantower.com"
}
variable "customer_id"{
    type = string
    default = "C00yc5oid" # See: https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F10070793%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=10070793&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a
}

resource "google_cloud_identity_group" "group" {
  display_name = "my-identity-group"

  parent = "customers/${var.customer_id}"
  # billing_project = var.project_id # Not an actual argument
  # user_project_override = true # Not an actual argument

  group_key {
    id = "my-identity-group@${var.domain_name}"
  }

  labels = {
    "cloudidentity.googleapis.com/groups.discussion_forum" = ""
  }
}
```

I assume I'm supposed to set the `billing_project` and `user_project_override` via the `gcloud` cli commands, but I don't know the commands for it.

Any idea how to set the `billing_project` and `user_project_override`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set those values in [Google Provider Configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference), not in `google_cloud_identity_group`.

Answer (score 1):

To add clarity to the accepted answer, include the following in the `provider` block:

```
provider "google" {
  project               = var.project_id
  billing_project       = var.project_id
  user_project_override = true
}
```